# Convert Byte Array to Int odd result Java and Kotlin

Tags: java, c#, android, kotlin

The contents of a `Byte` `Array` of size 4 are the following:
`{1, 0, 0, 0}`. This translates to the integer number `1` in C# when using `BitConverter.ToInt32(bytearray, 0);`

However, when converting this byte array to an `Integer` in Kotlin using the following code base I get the value `16777216` instead of the value of `1`.

```
var test0 = BigInteger(bytearray).toInt() = 16777216
var test1 = BigInteger(bytearray).toFloat() = 1.6777216
```

or

```
fun toInt32(bytes: ByteArray, index: Int): Int
{
    if (bytes.size != 4) 
        throw Exception("The length of the byte array must be at least 4 bytes long.")

    return 0xff 
        and bytes[index].toInt() shl 56 
        or (0xff and bytes[index + 1].toInt() shl 48) 
        or (0xff and bytes[index + 2].toInt() shl 40) 
        or (0xff and bytes[index + 3].toInt() shl 32)
}
```

I believe both methods of conversion are correct and the byte values are not signed.

Comment: Java works with "network byte order" which is big endian, while C# seems to work with little endian.

Comment: @Lothar Endianness is a hardware characteristic, not software. A C# on a big endian machine will work with big endian.

Comment: @itsme86 The Java Virtual Machine is essentially a hardware simulation, so there is no contradiction here.

Comment: @Lothar Your statement that C# works with little endian is misleading if not false.

Comment: @itsme86 While I think that I explained the effect sufficiently you might rephrase what I wrote and make an answer out of it.

Comment: To be more precise, `BigInteger(byte[])` assumes big-endian byte order, while `BitConverter.ToInt32` uses the endianness of the underlying hardware.

Comment: In C#, you should really be using [BitConvert.IsLittleEndian](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.islittleendian?view=netframework-4.8) to figure out if and how you should interpret your source data. This will allow your code to run correctly on either architecture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by @Lother and itsme86.

```
fun littleEndianConversion(bytes: ByteArray): Int {
    var result = 0
    for (i in bytes.indices) {
        result = result or (bytes[i].toInt() shl 8 * i)
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: How can I do the same conversion with bigEndian ?

Comment: byteArrayOf(0xF4.toByte(), 0x00.toByte())  is supposed to return 255 but actually returns -1?

Answer (score 5):

A tiny bit different solution which I think is a bit more efficient:

```
    private fun byteToInt(bytes: ByteArray): Int {
        var result = 0
        var shift = 0
        for (byte in bytes) {
            result = result or (byte.toInt() shl shift)
            shift += 8
        }
        return result
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is,

```
   fun toInt32(bytes:ByteArray):Int {
       if (bytes.size != 4) { 
           throw Exception("wrong len")
       }                   
       bytes.reverse()          
       return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).int           
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to eigenfeld's answer, but without needing to reverse the bytes first.

```kotlin
fun toInt32(bytes: ByteArray, index: Int): Int {
    require(bytes.size == 4) { "length must be 4, got: ${bytes.size}" }
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, index, 4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).int
}
```

Answer (score -16):

In C#, you have the following class:

`var test0 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytearray, 0)`